# What is the best php version to use with WordPress?

Tags: php, hosting

What is the best php version to use with WordPress... without going over the top.

Comment: https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/

Comment: the latest one?

Comment: as all "best" type of question this is so broad it is totally useless. best for what? what is the "top"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't (and shouldn't) be an answer with any *specific* version for this. New versions come out, old versions get discontinued.

- At the *minimum* you should use *supported* version of PHP. This ensures it still receives bug fixes and (or for less recent version) security updates.
- *Preferably* you should be use the *latest stable* version of PHP. This ensures you get best possible performance.

PHP site has handy [Supported Versions](http://php.net/supported-versions.php) page, which clearly covers currently relevant versions and roadmap for their support.

Comment: This is still theoretical, and not dealing with practical realities. At minimum use the most stable version that supports what you want to do. The version of PHP should not be the tail wagging the dog, as it were.

Answer (score 9):

### IMPORTANT EDIT

This has unknowingly came to my attention as it slipped my mind, PHP 5.4 have already reach EOL and the last security support was stopped on the 14th of September 2015.

According to [official documentation](http://php.net/supported-versions.php), PHP 5.5 will finally reach its EOL on the 10 of July 2016 (*Active support has already been stopped but this version will still get security updates until its final EOl date of 10 of July 2016*).

So to come back to the original question, you should be running on minimum at least PHP 5.5 now, but be sure to get ready to switch to PHP 5.6 within the next 8 months as from date of this answer

### ORIGINAL ANSWER

Wordpress are still stuck on the dinosaur PHP versions, so any PHP version newer or equal to 5.3 should do.

It is however very very important to note that **all** PHP versions prior to version 5.4 have been EOL'ed, the last version being 5.3 a year ago. In short, this means than any PHP version older than 5.4 are no longer supported or updated, which will cause huge security issues if you are still using it.

So, for safety, the bare minimum you should be running safely is PHP 5.4.x, where `x` should be the latest security release.

In short, to be rather safe than sorry, just like Wordpress, it is always always the best to have the latest available stable release installed.

Comment: How does one "validate a PHP version"

Comment: Check the [official docs](http://php.net/supported-versions.php) and my important update

Comment: It's all a little bit scary now!

Comment: Yes, each major PHP version has a set lifetime (*which slipped my mind completely, good you brought this up again*). Wordpress has the same policy, but unlike PHP, Wordpress brings out a new major version every 6 months

Comment: I'm looking for a new host but they don't tell you about the EOL thing

Comment: Rule of thumb, cheap hosts almost never support any version above PHP 5.3 and PHP 5.4 (*if you are really lucky*). They also hide important detail and focus on how low their prices are. Be prepared to pay for proper hosting unfortunately

Comment: This EOL stuff is more scare tactic than anything, otherwise you would see a lot more movement to newer versions. The reality is that older versions are better known and more stable, and for people running sites and apps for a business, stability is a lot more important than new bells and whistles.

Answer (score 4):

To run WordPress we recommend your host supports:

PHP version 5.6 or greater

MySQL version 5.5 or greater

Note: If you are in a legacy environment where you only have older PHP or MySQL versions, WordPress also works with PHP 5.2.4+ and MySQL 5.0+, but these versions have reached official End Of Life and as such may expose your site to security vulnerabilities.

For details please follow code link:

[Wordpress Requirements](https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/)

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for explanation with using 5.4 as minimum version :)

Comment: Note, this has slipped my mind, PHP 5.4 has already been EOL'ed a month ago. You should be running at least 5.5. See my update to my answer

Answer (score 3):

All the answers here don't take into account an actual, functioning Wordpress environment, but use arguments about end-of-life/support (that is, age). Who cares? What one really wants is stability and functionality. Therefore, one should use the latest version that an entire Wordpress system (with desired themes and plugins) will support. Latest because PHP generally has speed (and stability) improvements in newer versions, but not "the" latest, because stability may suffer.

There are still many plugins (especially those not updated recently) which have deprecated or unsupported PHP code in them, so running the latest and greatest PHP version will not work with those plugins (and themes). 5.6 is the safest, latest version with wide support (90+%), and 7.x is the very latest, and definitely has performance benefits, but a lot of wordpress themes and plugins will not function. Best is to test out your current system and see what your entire environment can work with. Try the PHP Compatibility Checker. It isn't 100% accurate, but gives you something to start with. https://wordpress.org/plugins/php-compatibility-checker/

Finally, PHP versions may have a needed or desired functionality, such as OpCache or php-fpm/mpm-event. In these cases, 5.5 and 5.6 will do.

Comment: If you want to see what the community in general uses: https://wptavern.com/php-7-is-now-more-widely-used-than-php-4

Comment: there is no way to run secure system on an insecure infrastructure, and there is no way to run stable system on unstable infrastture. By your logic I guess people should still use windows 95 because there is that one program that do not work in windows XP :(

Comment: @mark-kaplun If you think someone has written something preposterous, best to go back and check your understanding first. "an entire Wordpress system" does not imply ALL Wordpress systems, but rather a fully functional system and its requirements and limitations. In many cases, changing the requirements (for that one program that doesn't support a newer version, say, for example), is a better step to take.

Comment: no it is not "better" in any way, except for lazinees

Comment: Would it be better to swap out an old part on a bicycle with a newer part that does the same function, but better, since the old part isn't going to be upgraded by the manufacturer? Or are you just obtuse?

Comment: you are looking into taking technical debt https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_debt upon yourself. Technical debt like financial one has a tendency to accumulate effort that would be required to "repay" it over time, and many times you need to repay it at the worst time. There is nothing wrong with delaying addressing the debt for whatever known time, as long as you know that you need to address it, but a strategy to accumulate it forever always results in tears.

Comment: ... and internet related software enviroment is very dynamic and software changes state from actively developed to abandoned in a very fast pace. Delay enough and you will get stuck with a platform that in the extreme case can not be even deployed to any other server because the old OS you use do not support the new hardware that is available.

Comment: @MarkKaplun It escapes me how upgrading PHP earlier than needed creates additional Technical Debt. Instead that is called premature optimization, which as we know is "the root of all evil" (Tony Hoare). Really have no idea what is meant the reference to obsolete operating systems. No one is recommending keeping them around. But better take a look at how AWS Amazon Linux is essentially a modified CentOS 6.x and not the 7.x latest and greatest. Again, premature optimization, root of evil.

Comment: seriously, if you are going to have a pointless argument, at least learn the terms you use. This is not a premature optimization, as optimization have nothing to do with it. If you do not understand technical debt, maybe because you have never experienced the impact of it first hand, "when needed"  is usually the worst point in time to handle it. When you read again about the credit agency that exposed all the info about most of americans, keep in mind that it was because they didn't apply security fixes ASAP and waited "until it is needed"

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress now recommends using PHP 7 or above - see https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/

The minimum supported PHP version as of today is 5.2.4.

I would use the latest version of PHP, which is 7.1.

Answer (score 0):

Check the WordPress [Requirements](https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/) for the latest WordPress recommendation. Currently PHP version recommended is 7.2 (or greater).

[image]